# Clone Azure Repository on cPanel

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, cpanel

I am trying to clone Azure hosted repository on a cPanel account. I have generated public and private SSH keys from cPanel -> Manage SSH Keys section.

Later I have added the public key in my Azure account following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops). When I use the SSH URL (eg: git@ssh.dev.azure.com/MyProject) to clone the repository on cPanel it throws below exception

```
Error: (XID azuvpp) “/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/git” reported error code “128” when it ended:
Permission denied, please try again. Permission denied (password,publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Note - The idea here is to try implement CI/CD to automate push deployment on cPanel whenever there is a commit on master branch in Azure repository.

Open to ideas and suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and test that SSH access from the cPanel terminal (cPanel >> Home >> Advanced >> Terminal)

```
ssh -Tv git@ssh.dev.azure.com
```

Check in particular if your public/private ssh keys filenames are mentioned in the output (if your keys are not the standard default `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, you would need a `~/.ssh/config` file in order to specify the private key file path)

Comment: Does that connect Azure repo to cPanel and any push to azure repo automatically updates code in cPanel codebase?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy No: your question mention adding  the public key in your Azure account: that means you are trying to connect to Azure. Not to cPanel.

Comment: I am trying to connect Azure Repo to cPanel Git

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy That will "connect" them, but to clarify the SSH query: Your question is: "When I use the SSH URL (eg: git@ssh.dev.azure.com/MyProject) to clone the repository on cPanel". That means cPanel is using the Azure SSH URL to access the Azure repo in order to clone said repo to cPanel: the SSH is from cPanel to Azure, which is why you regitered your public key on Azure side.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy Any push to azure will be reflected on cPanel when you will do a `git pull`